# Is a PlastiDip paint job a viable alternative for a real paint job?

Tags: paint

Call me late, but I just found out about this whole ['PlastiDip'](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=&ie=UTF-8&q=plasti%20dip) thing last night, even after doing some [diligent research](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8548/diy-how-to-create-a-car-paint-booth-whats-involved) on diy car painting a while back. It seems there's a significant following of people who paint their entire *car* with this stuff.

While the majority of paint jobs I've seen are okay, and nothing I'd do on the ficticious Rolls Royce in my garage, there were some that did in fact look good enough to forego a traditional paint job and go this route.

My question is, what are the pros and cons of plasti dipping a whole car?

Comment: Check out http://www.forteforums.com/forums/do-yourself-articles/19465-why-plasti-dipping-your-entire-car-completely-stupid-thing-do.html I've never messed with it myself though.

Comment: I haven't used it either, though have heard good things about it. [Duplicolor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CT7St1XQl8E) has the stuff in a can, though they don't call it "dipping" ... Their product is pretty good from reviews I've read. Also, it seems [Dip Your Car](https://www.dipyourcar.com/) has some stuff going on as well. I don't think it would stand up to the "long haul", but if you wanted to change the look of your car without the worry of paint (you can easily change it back with either product), this or something like it is the product for you.

Comment: I would personally rather have a vinyl wrap made than use plastidip.

Comment: Finishing of [plastidip](https://www.besthvlpspraygun.com/comparison/spray-paint-vs-plasti-dip-vs-powder-coat/) is good, so its look really nice. But, it is not long lasting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did plastidip on a lot of things and my car, so I have a little bit of experience with it. Plastidip is not an alternativ for the real paint job at all. You need a good painted car to make plastidip looks good (same color, no scratches, bright color). The problem is the very low drown of plastidip. With the white car you can do whatever you want. On the black one you need thousands of layers to see the color you want. Also the good gloss effect is very hard to get. My yellow one holds only 1 year. After the winter I got some stains and I removed all the stuff (also not so easy as you think). Car wrapping is for me the better alternativ then plastidip.

Answer (score 1):

I did a full plastic dip on my car with a pearl topcoat (clear with metal flake mixed in).  I used the DipYourCar product with their spraying system.  Overall it came out pretty good for my first attempt at dipping, but there are many pitfalls.  It took more paint to cover than anticipated (that includes the clear), which is a big problem to have in the middle of the job.  Little mistakes like drips are very difficult to fix (unlike regular paint that you can sand and correct).  You have to be very careful peeling the masking tape off, like I said, mistakes are difficult to fix.  As far as wear and tear, the paint is very susceptible to stains (you can't get them off) and DO NOT let gas drip on it when filling up.  Finally, the Pearl Coat is showing some heavy UV wear after a year, even with proper cleaning a protecting.  If I were to do it again, I would stick to just the matte look, or base-coat clear-coat only, no pearl.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the stuff as the manufacturer intended. I've watched it peel off tool handles. There's NO way it's going onto my vehicle as a finish paint job, not even my lawn mower.

Comment: The coating which goes on tools is not what the OP is talking about. Please follow the links in my comment above to see the paint as it is a pretty cool product.

Comment: Ah. I SEE. So... it's INTENDED to be temporary, like an ink tattoo. When referred to by a trademarked name, one assumes that the trademarked name applies. Seems like the principle is overall the same - colored peelable plastic coatings. Further... I think my initial comment still applies, too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with dipping. Plastic can only last a few years under the sun's uv. real paint job last at least 10 years. No comparison.